# Dynamic to() in Apache Camel Route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am writing a demo program using Apache Camel. Out Camel route is being called from a Spring Boot scheduler and it will transfer file from the source directory C:\CamelDemo\inputFolder to the destination directory C:\CamelDemo\outputFolder

The Spring Boot scheduler is as under

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValue}")
    public void scheduleJob() {
        System.out.println("Scheduler executing");
        String inputEndpoint = "file:C:\\CamelDemo\\inputFolder?noop=true&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true";
        String outputEndpoint = "file:C:\\CamelDemo\\outputFolder?autoCreate=false";

        Map<String, Object> headerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headerMap.put("inputEndpoint", inputEndpoint);
        headerMap.put("outputEndpoint", outputEndpoint);

        producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct:transferFile", null, headerMap);
        System.out.println("Scheduler complete");
    }
}
```

The Apache Camel route is as under

```
@Component
public class FileTransferRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliverDelay(1000)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));

        from("direct:transferFile")
            .log("Route reached")
            .log("Input Endpoint: ${in.headers.inputEndpoint}")
            .log("Output Endpoint: ${in.headers.outputEndpoint}")
            .pollEnrich().simple("${in.headers.inputEndpoint}")
            .recipientList(header("outputEndpoint"));
            //.to("file:C:\\CamelDemo\\outputFolder?autoCreate=false")
    }
}
```

When I am commenting out the line for recipientList() and uncommenting the to() i.e. givig static endpoint in to(), the flow is working. But when I am commenting to() and uncommenting recipientList(), it is not working. Please help how to route the message to the dynamic endpoint (outputEndpoint)?

Comment: When I am setting the outputEndpoint value in a property in Exchange and getting the exchangeProperty in recipientList(), it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pollEnrich` without specifying an `AggregationStrategy`: in this case, Camel will create a new OUT message from the retrieved resource, without combining it to the original IN message: this means you will lose the headers previously set on the IN message.

See documentation : https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/enrich-eip.html#_a_little_enrich_example_using_java

> **strategyRef**   Refers to an AggregationStrategy to be used to merge the reply from the external service, into a single outgoing message. By default Camel will use the reply from the external service as outgoing message.

A simple solution would be to define a simple `AggregationStrategy` on your `pollEnrich` component, which simply copies headers from the IN message to the new OUT message (note that you will then use the original IN message body, but in your case it's not a problem I guess)

```
    from("direct:transferFile")
            .log("Route reached")
            .log("Input Endpoint: ${in.headers.inputEndpoint}")
            .log("Output Endpoint: ${in.headers.outputEndpoint}")
            .pollEnrich().simple("${in.headers.inputEndpoint}")
            .aggregationStrategy((oldExchange, newExchange) -> {
                // Copy all headers from IN message to the new OUT Message
                newExchange.getIn().getHeaders().putAll(oldExchange.getIn().getHeaders());
                return newExchange;
            })
            .log("Output Endpoint (after pollEnrich): ${in.headers.outputEndpoint}")
            .recipientList(header("outputEndpoint"));
            //.to("file:C:\\var\\CamelDemo\\outputFolder?autoCreate=false");
```